# Asp.net UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication not working in Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, owin, openid, openid-connect

I am using UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication to authenticate users.  My application code works fine locally.  But, when I run it on Azure, the SecurityTokenValidated event is never fired.  Consequently, the code runs fine but the user is never authenticated.  I am not sure if the issue is with my code or with Azure.  This is being used in a Web Form, Asp.net application (not Core).  I use the Azure trace feature to log.  I can see that only "RedirectToIdentityProvider" is fired.  No other event gets called.  Here is my code:

**Startup.Auth.Vb:**

```
 Public Sub ConfigureAuth(app As IAppBuilder)

      Dim clientId As String = ""
      Dim authority As String = ""
      Dim redirectURI As String

      Trace.TraceInformation("Hit Config Auth function")
      ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
      JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap = New Dictionary(Of String, String)

      app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType("Cookies")
      app.UseCookieAuthentication(New CookieAuthenticationOptions() With {
                .AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                .CookieManager = New SystemWebCookieManager
            })  


      redirectURI = appSettings("ID_Redirect_URI")
      clientId = appSettings("ID_ClientID")
      authority = appSettings("ID_Authority")
      Trace.TraceInformation(redirectURI)
      Trace.TraceInformation(clientId)
      Trace.TraceInformation(authority)

      Trace.TraceInformation("creating OpenIDAuthOptions")
      Dim OpenIdAuthOption = New OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions() With {
           .SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
           .Authority = authority,
           .RequireHttpsMetadata = False,
           .ClientId = clientId,
           .ResponseType = "id_token",
           .Scope = "openid profile roles",
           .RedirectUri = redirectURI,
           .PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectURI,
           .Notifications = New OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications() With {
                .AuthenticationFailed = Function(ctx)
                      Trace.TraceInformation("Auth Failed event")
                      Return Task.FromResult(0)
                 End Function,
                 .SecurityTokenReceived = Function(ctx)
                      Trace.TraceInformation("Sec Token Recieved event")
                      Return Task.FromResult(0)
                  End Function,
                  .MessageReceived = Function(ctx)
                      Trace.TraceInformation("Message Recieved event")
                      Return Task.FromResult(0)
                      End Function,
                  .SecurityTokenValidated = Function(ctx)
                     Trace.TraceInformation("Security token validated")                          
                     Return Task.FromResult(0)
                     End Function,
                  .AuthorizationCodeReceived = Function(ctx)
                     Trace.TraceInformation("Auth Code Recieved event")
                     Return Task.FromResult(0)
                     End Function,
                  .RedirectToIdentityProvider = Function(context)
                   Trace.TraceInformation("start of RedirectToIDProvider")
                    Return Task.FromResult(0)
                    End Function
                    }
            }

            Trace.TraceInformation("adding OpenIdAuthOptyions")
            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(OpenIdAuthOption)
            Trace.TraceInformation("finihsed adding OpenIdAuthOptyions")
        End Sub
```

As I mentioned above, this code works fine locally.  It only does not work when hosted on Azure.  When running locally, the events are fired in this order:

1. RedirectToIdentityProvider
2. Message Received
3. Security Token Received
4. Security Token Validated

But, in Azure, only RedirectToIdentityProvider is fired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changed your `Action to take when request is not authenticated` in App Service `Authentication/Authorization` section in the azure portal from `LogIn with Azure Active Directory` to `Allow Anonymous requests`. As shown on the picture below:

[image]

Then the `SecurityTokenValidated` would be fired. App services auth takes place outside of you app, so customized auth code in your app never gets a chance to run. When you turn that off it allows your app to handle the auth itself the same way it does locally.

Here is the [similar](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/issues/190) issue you could refer to.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the application manifest of the application definition on Azure to set the "oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow" property to true from false.

1. Go to the Azure Portal,
2. Select to Azure Active Directory
3. Select App Registrations
4. Select your app.
5. Click on Manifest
6. Find the value oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow and change it's value to true
7. Click Save

2) In your startup.cs file, change the following:

```
ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code
to
ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken
```

and see if it helps.