# using UseCookiesAuthentication to authorize the MVC Controller Action, it works locally, gives issue when the application is deployed in azure

Tags: c#, azure, owin, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-identity-2

I have the *MVC application*, using the Owin and Asp.Net Identity, and using the `useCookieauthentication`

During login process, I have added the custom claim, and I gets properly sign-in. ```

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel loginViewModel)
    {
        var user = UserManager.FindByName(loginViewModel.UserName);
        var signInStatus = UserManager.CheckPassword(user, loginViewModel.Password);

        if (signInStatus)
        {
            user.Claims.Add(new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserClaim() { ClaimType = "CustomClaim", ClaimValue = loginViewModel.UserName.Trim() });
            SignInManager.SignIn(user, true, false);
            return Redirect(url);
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
            return View(loginViewModel);
        }
    }
```

When I get the callback to my one of Action method, I try to retrieve Claim Custom Claim that I have stored during login process. Locally when I run and debug this code it works correctly as expected. But when I deploy the application to azure I am unable to get the custom claim value.

```
       public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var claimsPrincipal = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal;
            var customClaimValue = claimsPrincipal.Identities.First().Claims.First(x => x.Type.Equals("CustomClaim")).Value;
            return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to try, Let me know if it still doesn't work for you, Posting as per my recent experience which i covered in my other answer.

Also please troubleshoot further to understand more on the inner stack details.

- As @Joey Cai mentioned in his answer ,Change your `**Action to take when request is not authenticated in App Service**` 
  Authentication/Authorization section in the azure portal from LogIn with Azure Active Directory to `**Allow Anonymous requests**`. As shown on the picture below:

[image]

- If above option doesn't work out try below:

  Try changing the application manifest of the application definition on Azure to set the "oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow" property to true from false.

  - Go to the Azure Portal,
  - Select to Azure Active Directory
  - Select App Registrations
  - Select your app.
  - Click on Manifest
  - Find the value oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow and change it's value to true
  - Click Save

[Asp.net UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication not working in Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55225902/asp-net-useopenidconnectauthentication-not-working-in-azure)

Hope it helps.